# python dask dataframe write json file with array format

Tags: python, pandas, dask, dask-dataframe

I am trying to read a large CSV file and then loading the data as JSON file.
The following code is working fine but the data is writing as JSON object in each line on JSON file.

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd
cols=['Name','State']
df=dd.read_csv('F:\csvs\stack.csv', low_memory=False, usecols=cols,
dtype={'Name':str,'State':str}
)
df.to_json(r'F:\csvs\stack',  orient ='records', compression = 'infer')
```

Above code writing the data as JSON object in each line

```
{"Name":"John","State":"TS"}
{"Name":"Paha","State":"MK"}
```

**How to write the data as JSON array like below?**

```
[{"Name":"John","State":"TS"},{"Name":"Paha","State":"MK"}]
```

**By default files are creating file type as `.part`, How to create files with `.json` extension.**

Comment: Dask is working exactly as described in the docs: https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.dataframe.to_json.html. Did you try lines=False?

Comment: And yeah dask writes partitioned files. If your data is small enough to fit into memory you can always compute the dataframe to dump it into pandas and then use pd.DataFrame.to_json instead

Comment: @MichaelDelgado `lines=False` solved the issue. Now it writing the data in file as expected `[{"key":"value"},{"key":"value}]`. Thank you!. How to change the file extensions from `.part` to `.json`?

Comment: @MichaelDelgado I have scientific notations in CSV file. what is the best way to handle to exponential value in exported JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Dask is oriented at processing your data partition by partition. This is what allows you to run through datasets bigger than system memory and to run tasks in parallel.

Since each partition is processed independently and in any order, any write operation needs to go to a separate file to prevent problems from interleaving. This is why JSONlines format and multiple files is the right choice here.

If you must produce a single output JSON object, then your data must be small enough to fit in memory, and you could `.compute()` the dataframe to pandas and use the options pandas provides.

Alternatively, a streaming routine to run through the files and concatenate their contents appropriately would be easy to write in python or text processing language such as awk.

(outputting to a single file was so often requested for CSVs, that dask did put in extra effort to make this possible. You could request this for JSON, but I don't expect too much interest)